# create a parameter variable <def_par> to store parameter variables

Tags: r

I want to create a parameter variable <def_par> to store parameter variables. I have a dataset.
is this right:

```
def_par <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
```

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. If you just want to assign values to a vector use something like `def_par <- c(1, 2.4, 5, 1000)`. _`par` can be used to set or query graphical parameters._

Comment: This is exactly I am asked to do. I have a dataset the variables are frequency, cumulitative frequency,relative frequency

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.